# Node JS operating system date time

Tags: node.js, datetime, operating-system

I have created simple application to print date and time in Node JS.
I will use it to test my time based events in application without restarting the application.

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(new Date());
},1000);
```

It gives O/P: Mon Jan 01 2017 01:55:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

**Now, I am changing time of my OS to Mon Dec 01 2016 01:55:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

**But node application prints Mon Jan 01 2017 01:55:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and not the updated time of OS.**

Operating system is Linux and Winows both.

Comment: should not happen if your server is running locally it will pick up the time from your system, did you restart your server.

Comment: I am amusing same thing, that is should get date from system. But, it is not. Also, if i print date in other language it print undated OS date.

Answer (score -1):

Use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to change the OS time on ubuntu.
For windows use
`tzutil /s "time zone"`
to set the time zone and `tzutil /l` to list available time zones.

Comment: Any idea about windows operating system?